# '\0' appears when parse xml with xerces

Tags: c++, xml, xerces

Here is my code:

```
XercesDOMParser domParser;
MemBufInputSource* basic_mem = new MemBufInputSource(
    (const XMLByte* )(xmlString.c_str()),//xmlString is a std::string that contains xml
    xmlString.length(),//this std::string's length
    "dummy");
ParserErrorHandler parserErrorHandler;

domParser.setErrorHandler(&parserErrorHandler);
domParser.setExitOnFirstFatalError(true);
domParser.setValidationConstraintFatal(true);
domParser.setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Auto);
domParser.setDoNamespaces(true);    
domParser.setDoSchema(true);  
domParser.parse(*basic_mem);
```

My xml string is like this:

```
xmlString = "\
<root>\r\n\
<somenode someattr="abc@def"/>\r\n\
</root>"
```

i then use xmlString.replace('@','\0') to add '\0' in.

here is the problem: if xmlString contains a '\0' inside, parser will report an error:
"unexpected end of input". i think it's because the '\0'. but i am sure xmlString is       intact, and xmlString.length() is correct.
so i tried to move this '\0' into CDATA:

```
xmlString = "\
<root>\r\n\
<somenode>\r\n\
<![CDATA[abc\0def]]>\r\n\
</somenode>\r\n\
</root>"
```

then parser report "unexpected end of　CDATA"．．．
what can i do to fix this problem? Any suggestions will done!!

Comment: `NUL` character is not permitted in XML. See [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets).

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ cstrings are terminated by `\0`, so you can tell where string ends without passing around it's length as separate argument. Generally, you don't want to put this character into the middle of such string, because you will loose everything that follows that character.

Comment: thank you, but binaries can be passed into std::string, some std::string functions support this feature, like append(string,length), or replace(pos,length,string), i am sure that although there is a '\0' inside, string's length is correct, so i think it's a problem happens when or after i call MemBufInputSource(), but i am not sure about this...